# How to correctly ldapmodify replace olcAccess lines?

Tags: debian, ldap, openldap, access-control-list

This is a part from olcDatabase={1}hdb.ldif

```
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange
 by self write
 by anonymous auth
 by dn="cn=admin,dc=somesite,dc=com" write
 by * none
olcAccess: {1}to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: {2}to *
 by self write
 by dn="cn=admin,dc=somesite,dc=com" write
 by * read
```

I would like to append `by dn="cn=anotheruser,ou=Users,dc=somesite,dc=com" write` to the `{0}` and `{2}` line.

Before I destroy my LDAP server, **is the following LDIF correct?**

```
dn: olcDatabase{1}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange
        by dn="cn=admin,dc=somesite,dc=com" write
        by dn="uid=anotheruser,ou=Users,dc=somesite,dc=com" write
        by anonymous auth
        by self write
        by * none
olcAccess: {2}to *
 by self write
 by dn="cn=admin,dc=somesite,dc=com" write
 by dn="cn=anotheruser,ou=Users,dc=somesite,dc=com" write
 by * read
```

With: `ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f ./changes.ldif`

**My concerns are:**

- there are 3 `olcAccess:` lines, I did not include the {1} line
  so would it still be there after committing the ldif changes
- is the `replace: olcAccess` line correct?

Comment: Please tell me this isn't managing `posixAccount` `dn`s. Allowing such a `dn` to change its `uidNumber` and `gidNumber` to 0 is a serious security problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This ldif worked for me, with previous command

```
dn: olcDatabase{1}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange
        by dn="cn=admin,dc=somesite,dc=com" write
        by dn="uid=anotheruser,ou=Users,dc=somesite,dc=com" write
        by anonymous auth
        by self write
        by * none
olcAccess: {1}to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: {2}to *
 by self write
 by dn="cn=admin,dc=somesite,dc=com" write
 by dn="cn=anotheruser,ou=Users,dc=somesite,dc=com" write
 by * read
```

Comment: On my machine it was `dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config` with an '=' after olcDatabase.